# How do I get the subject and body of every mail that I click to my add on that I created?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

> I want to create an add-on similar to Trello. Every time you open a
> mail, Trello automatically fills in the "Name" and "Description"
> fields for you. The name here is the "subject" of the mail and the
> description is the "body" of the mail. I want to achieve the same
> thing.
>
> [trello-image-example][1] [trello-image-example][2] [my-add-on][3]
> Here is my code:
> https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/pejasapero.php
>
> I get this when I run my code:
>
> [content-not-available-image][4]
>
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykRJU.png   [2]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTAv9.png   [3]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgHGw.png   [4]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibWzu.png

Comment: Feverr is the right place for it...

Comment: Yes. it is very much possible.

Comment: Nobody will do it from scratch here, post what you've tried so far and where in code you need help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to create a `Workspace Add-on`.

[Here is a sample](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/teams-addon-sample) which shows, how to get data from a Email and integrate it into the Workspace Add-on.

Comment: When I copy the appscript.json to my editor, it throws an error saying "Service not found: drive v3".

Comment: See [step two](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/teams-addon-sample#step_2_update_the_script_manifest) in the instructions. You need to set the scopes.